# How do i make a blinking pixels?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 i have a timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdetected == true)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

In the class CloudEnteringAlert at the top i did:

```
public static bool cloudsdetected;
```

Then set it to false as default:

```
static CloudEnteringAlert()
        {
            cloudsdetected = false;
        }
```

Then in a method i have i set it to true or false:

```
if (clouds.Count == 0)
            {
                cloudsdetected = false;
                clouds = null;
            }
            else
            {
                cloudsdetected = true;
            }
```

clouds is a List if the List is not empty that's mean there are clouds.
That's mean i want the pixels in the paint event to blink.

In the paint event of pictureBox1 i have:

```
foreach (PointF pt in clouds)
                {
                    e.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, pt.X * (float)currentFactor, pt.Y * (float)currentFactor, 2f, 2f);
                }
```

Now this just color the pixels in yellow.
Now i want to use the Timer1 somehow that if cloudsdetected = true; then enable true the timer and also each second change the color of the pixels in the paint event from Yellow to transparent color  or red color and back to yellow so it will look like its blinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the color value in your timer. One way to go about it:

Have an array of cloud colors:

```
// blinking colors: yellow, red, yellow, transparent, repeat...
var cloudColors = new [] { Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Transparent }
// current color index
var cloudColorIndex = 0;
```

In the timer event set the color index:

```
private void cloudTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cloudColorIndex = (cloudColorIndex + 1) % cloudColors.Length;
}
```

In your paint event you can now use the current color instead of a fixed one:

```
foreach (PointF pt in clouds)
{
    e.FillEllipse(cloudColors[cloudColorIndex], pt.X * (float)currentFactor, pt.Y * (float)currentFactor, 2f, 2f);
}
```